# Riot Js Updating tag

Tags: javascript, object, this, riot.js

If i'm on the form tag and I want to update the nav tag. When a event happens on the form tag. How can I update the nav without riot.update();

```
  <form id="signup" class="row" action="" method="">
       <ul class="small-10 small-centered columns">
          <li>
            <div class="error" if={this.email.error}>Required</div>
            <input onfocus="{focus}" onblur="{blur}" type="text" name="email" value="" placeholder="Email Address">
         </li>
      </ul>
    </form>

</script>

    this.focus = function() {
        this.session.focused = true;
        riot.update();
    };

    this.blur = function() {
       this.session.focused = false;
       riot.update();
    };

</script>
```

different page

```
  <nav class="{show: this.open === true, fix-header: this.session.focused}">

    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like [redux](http://redux.js.org/) to store global app state.